# ranges-v3 / sort confusion

Tags: boost, range, c++17, range-v3

I'm a bit simple it seems as I'm not quite able to see clearly the cause of this error on the line marked error below.

std::sort and boost::sort picks up the default predicate, but ranges-v3 doesn't for some reason. This is ranges-v3 0.36. Similar error on clang 6/7 & gcc 7/8.

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>


namespace hana = boost::hana;

template< typename T = int>
struct point_t {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(point_t<T>, (T, x), (T, y));

  constexpr bool operator<(const point_t<T> &b) const noexcept {
    return hana::less(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));
  };
};

int main() {

  std::vector<point_t<point_t<>>> all;

  boost::sort(all); // OK
  std::sort(std::begin(all), std::end(all)); //OK

  ranges::sort(all, std::less<point_t<point_t<>>>()); // OK
  ranges::sort(all, hana::less); // OK

  ranges::sort(all); // error no matching function for call to object of type 'const with_braced_init_args<ranges::v3::sort_fn>'

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casey answered quickly via the [range-v3 issue list](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/851).

Here is his comment as text as requested instead of the original image I placed here:

> `ranges::sort` without a comparator argument requires the type to be
>   sorted to model the [`StrictTotallyOrdered`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/StrictTotallyOrdered) concept. That means
>   the type must define all of `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` with
>   consistent semantcs.

To which I replied there:

> Thank you for getting back so quickly. I understand now. I must say
>   it's a little disappointing it is incompatible with `std::sort` and
>   `boost::sort` requirements. That is the price we pay for `range-v3`
>   loveliness I guess.
>
> Thanks again, --Matt.

It is unfortunate the requirements are higher than `std::sort` and `boost::sort` so that code will not *just* work. I understand the motivation.

For the curious, `std::rel_ops` and `boost/operators` seemed to interfere with my goal for aggregate initialisation support for introspectable structs, so I ended up resorting to macros (similar to below), sadly.

I will play some more and look for a better static polymorphic solution.

Kind regards,

--Matt.

```
#define JEST_STRUCT(T)                                                         \
  constexpr bool operator==(const T &b) const noexcept {                       \
    return hana::equal(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));              \
  };                                                                           \
                                                                               \
  constexpr bool operator!=(const T &b) const noexcept {                       \
    return hana::not_equal(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));          \
  };                                                                           \
                                                                               \
  constexpr bool operator<(const T &b) const noexcept {                        \
    return hana::less(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));               \
  };                                                                           \
                                                                               \
  constexpr bool operator<=(const T &b) const noexcept {                       \
    return hana::less_equal(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));         \
  };                                                                           \
                                                                               \
  constexpr bool operator>(const T &b) const noexcept {                        \
    return hana::greater(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));            \
  };                                                                           \
                                                                               \
  constexpr bool operator>=(const T &b) const noexcept {                       \
    return hana::greater_equal(hana::to_tuple(*this), hana::to_tuple(b));      \
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that would be both polite and a good idea. Thanks Nicol. Changed to text with a reference to the github issue and expanded with a macro solution for this particular case.

Comment: Don't be disappointed. A constrained generic library would be not be a success if those constraints didn't foster soundness and equational reasoning. Why add constraints at all if not to gain some ability to reason at a higher level about the semantics of your code? That should be the ultimate goal of any generic library design.

Comment: Wise words. Full-featured correctness is a noble goal for us all. Fitting in the past too, but I favour breaking things at the end of the day. Will be much better when the spaceship lands and even better with Ranges. Especially liking the GPU ranges work. Consolidating kernel ops with Ranges is a thing of beauty. Thank you Eric for your work and incredible persistence.